# self.dismiss resets parent view controller's screen data

Tags: swift, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller inside the ParentViewController:

```
let item = getCurrentItem()
let presentViewController = viewController as! TestViewController
    presentViewController.id = item.id
    presentViewController.dismissController { // my custom delegate to inform the parent vc
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // presenting view controller is closing then viewWillAppear will be triggered
    }

self.present(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when dismiss is called, the ParentViewController's global arrays and variables are back to their initial values.

```
class ParentViewController {

    // MARK: - Stored Properties

    private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    private var items = [String:[Item]]()
    private var screenLoaded: Bool = false

    // MARK: - Controller Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // after dismiss is called viewWillAppear gets hit but the "screenLoaded" is always false
        if !screenLoaded {
            screenLoaded = true                
        }

        // items is initialised as well
    }

    private func openPopover() {
       let item = getCurrentItem()
       let presentViewController = viewController as! TestViewController
           presentViewController.id = item.id
           presentViewController.dismissController { // my custom delegate to inform the parent vc
               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // presenting view controller is closing then viewWillAppear will be triggered
        }

        self.present(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)   
    }
}
```

How can I keep the parent view controller's original state after the dismiss is called?

Comment: `private var items = [String:[Item]]()` & `private var screenLoaded: Bool = false` this two beck to initital value ??

Comment: Yes they are back to their initial values. What I understood is that when dismiss is called the entire parent view controller is initialised. But there should be a way to prevent this.

Comment: Where u using this `openPopover` method ?

Comment: It is called by a button outlet. Then the user taps on a button the outlet function calls the openPopover method.@IBAction func tab1Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
       openPopover()
    }

Comment: your are dismissing and presenting same viewController `presentViewController`?

Comment: Yes. let presentViewController = viewController as! TestViewController. Basically the TestViewController is being presented and then dismissed on the ParentViewController.

Comment: can i know why you are presenting one view controller than again dismissing it ?

Comment: Do you want to passback data in your parentview Controller ??

Comment: How it works is, the user opens the popover, does some stuff and when s(he) taps to the close button on the popover, the "dismissController" is called. ParentViewController then dismisses the child in here. Yes, there will be some data will be passed from child to parent in the future. That's why I am using a delegate.

Comment: So you want to present a view controller thn user should work some stuff there thn when click close btn it will be close right ?? or u want its will be close but ur parent vc data will be still updated ?

Comment: What I need is to keep the parent view controller's data after the dismiss is called; dismiss shouldn't reset everything.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging Apple's documentations finally I found the following solution and it works for me. Hope it helps someone in the future.

[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/overcurrentcontext][1]

```
presentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Also, if there is a tabbar, the bottom of the child view controller will be under it if you set the presentation style to **overCurrentContext**. The workaround is to present the child view controller from the window's rootViewController.

```
sender.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now when the dismiss is called viewWillAppear is not triggered and I can keep the parent view controller's data and it's state.